# How to know which version of TLS is support by node js 8.9.1 version

Tags: node.js, express, hapi

I am using node version 8.9.1 and wwant to know which version of TLS does it use by default.

I tried googling and looked at the node js documentation but could not find the answer

Comment: You can check `openssl` version with `node -p process.versions | grep openssl` [ref](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20248)

Comment: when i run that command it shows openssl version as 1.0.21. What should i conclude from this @GabrielBleu

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a self signed certificate with :

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

It will create `key.pem` and `cert.pem` files in current directory, you can then start a server with :

```
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

const server = tls.createServer(options, (socket) => {
  console.log('server connected',
          socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized', socket.getProtocol());
  socket.write('welcome!\n');
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

and connect to it using `openssl s_client` :

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Testing on node v8.11.3 will output :

```
server bound
server connected unauthorized TLSv1.2
```

ref :

- [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)
- [tls.createServer([options][, secureConnectionListener])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)
- [tlsSocket.getProtocol()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getprotocol)

Comment: Thanks @Gabrial node 8.9.1 also uses TLSv1.2 version by default

Comment: If your JavaScript is too old to understand the => syntax, replace "(socket) => {" with "function(socket) {" and replace "() => {" with "function() {".  (I have to support a legacy node v0.10.38.)

Comment: He didnt ask how to generate a certificate?